# ScroolToTop show and hide based on user's scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scrollbar

How can show and hide a dive of scrolltotop. 
Condition: 
1. when user scrool down to 80 px it will be shown
2.if user clicks on it it it will take user to the top.
3. if a user stay 2  or more seconds in a certain position(it may maby 200px or more or less), the scroolbar also hidden. If he scroll up or down, the scroolbar visible then.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#scrollup").hide('slow')

    $(window).scroll(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > 80) {
            $("#scrollup").show('slow');
        }
        if ($(window).scrollTop() < 80) {
            $("#scrollup").hide('slow');
        }
    });

    $(".scrollup").click(function () {
        $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 500);
        return false;
    });
});
```

i have done 1 and 2 condition , but how can i implement no 3?

Answer (score 1):

Add `setInterval(function(){ $("#scrollup").hide('slow'); }, 2000);` and clear it on scroll

```
var idleInterval=null;
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#scrollup").hide('slow');

    $(window).scroll(function (e) {
        if(idleInterval != null)
        clearTimeout(idleInterval);
        idleInterval = setInterval(function(){ $("#scrollup").hide('slow'); }, 2000);
        idleTime = 0;
        e.preventDefault();
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > 80) {
            $("#scrollup").show('slow');
        }
        if ($(window).scrollTop() < 80) {
            $("#scrollup").hide('slow');
        }
    });

    $(".scrollup").click(function () {
        $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 500);
        return false;
    });
});
```

**Demo:-**

```js
var idleInterval=null;
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#scrollup").hide('slow');

    $(window).scroll(function (e) {
        if(idleInterval != null)
        clearTimeout(idleInterval);
        idleInterval = setInterval(function(){ $("#scrollup").hide('slow'); }, 2000);
        idleTime = 0;
        e.preventDefault();
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > 80) {
            $("#scrollup").show('slow');
        }
        if ($(window).scrollTop() < 80) {
            $("#scrollup").hide('slow');
        }
    });

    $(".scrollup").click(function () {
        $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 500);
        return false;
    });
});
```

```css
#pagewrap{
  height:1000px;
}
#scrollup {
    position: fixed;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    background: red;
    bottom: 30px;
    right: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="pagewrap">
 <h1>Demo</h1>
 <h2><a href="http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/animated-scroll-to-top">Animated Scroll to Top</a></h2>
<div id="scrollup">
  scroll to top
</div>

</div>
```